# Dynamic dropdown boxes not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My website has a search bar comprised of 5 different dropdown boxes. The option selected in the first dropdown box influences the options available in the second and last dropdown box. I've managed to make this work for the second dropdown box but not the last. I tried to achieve this for the last dropddown box by duplicating the javascript and changing the values from s2 to s5 and then changing the optionArray but this stops the second dropbox from working and has no effect on the 5th dropdown box. How do I make the selected option in dropdown 1 influence the options in both dropdown 2 and dropdown 5?

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  
  if (s1.value == "Rifle") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["Bolt-Action","Bolt-Action"],["Single-shot","Single-shot"], ["Lever Action", "Lever Action"]];
  } else if (s1.value == "Shotgun") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["Pump-Action","Pump-Action"],["Folding","Folding"], ["Lever Action", "Lever Action"]];
  }
  
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (let option in optionArray) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionArray[option][0];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option][1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
function populate(s1, s5) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s5 = document.getElementById(s2);
  
  if (s1.value == "Rifle") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["22LR","22LR"],["17HMR","17HMR"], ["9mm", "9mm"]];
  } else if (s1.value == "Shotgun") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["12G","12G"],["20G","20G"], ["410G", "410G"]];
  }
  
  s5.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (let option in optionArray) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionArray[option][0];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option][1];
    s5.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.gunlink.co.uk/products.php">
    <select name="slct 1" id="slct 1" onchange="populate('slct 1','slct 2','slct 5')">
        <option disabled selected="Gun Type">Gun Type</option>
        <option value="Rifle">Rifle</option>
        <option value="Shotgun">Shotgun</option>
    </select>
    -------------

    <select name="slct 2" id="slct 2">
    <option disabled selected="Action">Action</option>
    </select>
    -------------
    <select name="slct 3" id="slct 3">
        <option disabled selected="Make">Make</option>
    </select>
    -------------
        <select name="slct 4" id="slct 4">
        <option disabled selected="Model">Model</option>
    </select>
    -------------
    <select name="slct 5" id="slct 5">
        <option disabled selected=".Cal">.Cal</option>
    </select>
    -------------
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The ids on your select boxes have spaces in them, which isn't valid and could be the reason you're having some issues. Classes can have spaces, but would be treated as multiple classes, but there can only be one id on an html element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment anymore, but the reason it may work on one element and not the rest is because javascript is likely treating your id as "slct" rather than "slct 1" etc, which is why it works for one and not the rest. Try taking the space out of your ids and the strings you're passing to your populate function and see if they populate correctly.

Comment: I changed the ids and hasn't seemed to solve the issue. If I remove the second function code the second dropbox works as it should even with the space in the ids. I've got a feeling the second function code is rewriting the original code hence the second dropbox stops working. I think you're right about this being an issue with population

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://www.gunlink.co.uk/products.php">
    <select name="slct 1" id="slct-1" onchange="populate('slct-1','slct-2','slct-5')">
        <option disabled selected="Gun Type">Gun Type</option>
        <option value="Rifle">Rifle</option>
        <option value="Shotgun">Shotgun</option>
    </select>
    -------------

    <select name="slct-2" id="slct-2">
    <option disabled selected="Action">Action</option>
    </select>
    -------------
    <select name="slct 3" id="slct-3">
        <option disabled selected="Make">Make</option>
    </select>
    -------------
        <select name="slct 4" id="slct-4">
        <option disabled selected="Model">Model</option>
    </select>
    -------------
    <select name="slct 5" id="slct-5">
        <option disabled selected=".Cal">.Cal</option>
    </select>
    -------------
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

```
function populate(s1,s2,s5) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  var s5= document.getElementById(s5);
  if (s1.value == "Rifle") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["Bolt-Action","Bolt-Action"],["Single-shot","Single-shot"], ["Lever Action", "Lever Action"]];
  } else if (s1.value == "Shotgun") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["Pump-Action","Pump-Action"],["Folding","Folding"], ["Lever Action", "Lever Action"]];
  }
  
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (let option in optionArray) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionArray[option][0];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option][1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
   
  if (s1.value == "Rifle") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["22LR","22LR"],["17HMR","17HMR"], ["9mm", "9mm"]];
  } else if (s1.value == "Shotgun") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["12G","12G"],["20G","20G"], ["410G", "410G"]];
  }
  
  s5.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (let option in optionArray) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionArray[option][0];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option][1];
    s5.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ov4swak9/